# Advanced issues on inheriting parent classes

Tags: python

How to make a function of the parent class not inherit from the child class and can be accessed outside the class at the same time?
like this

```
class a:
  def only_a_have():
      print(1)

class b(a)
     pass
a().only_a_have() success
b().only_a_have() error
```

Comment: I think this might be a desing problem, check if you really need to inherit

Comment: I agree it might be a design problem and you may be asking yourself why instead of how

Answer (score 1):

You should raise a `NotImplementedError` exception:

```
class a:
    def only_a_have():
        print(1)
    def everybody_have():
        print(2)

class b(a)
    def only_a_have():
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also make another parent class for `a` and `b`:

```
class x:
    # common code for a and b
    pass

class a(x):
    def only_a_have():
        print(1)

class b(x):
    # code only b has
    pass
```